# query_posts adding two “post-entry” divs

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm currently making a worpress theme. In the loop I want to have two "post-entry" divs, one that's small that goes next to my post thumb, and one for without the thumb.

I know that I need to do a `<?php` if which I've done, but I seem to have messed up somewhere and I can't see how. I have set my loop in a `query_posts`, but still it's not functioning properly. Here is the code I'm using if it helps make sense:

```
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
<?php query_posts();
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!--Begin Post-->
<div class="post">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>

<div class="post-thumb">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<div class="post-entry-1">

<? } else { ?>

<!--Begin Post Entry-->
<div class="post-entry-2">
<?php } ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div class="post-meta"><?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?> Posted <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <?php _e('in'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php the_author(); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>  <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?></div>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<!--End Post Entry-->

</div>

</div>
<!--End Post-->

<div class="clear"></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { ?><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="left"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div class="right"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
<?php } ?>

<?php else : ?>
<h3>Not Found</h3>
<p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.</p>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, as I have been stuck on this for a few days now.

Comment: Could you please add your desired HTML markup? I am not sure what is the issue with your current code.

Comment: What isn't working?  What appears on the screen?  It isn't clear what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry I tried to add all the code I've used but it wouldn't let me. What i'm trying to do is, if a post has an image for it to generate a post thumbnail as i'm using the_excerpt() on my index page. For the posts that have a thumbnail, i'm trying to get the "post-entry-1 to go next to it. But if there isn't a thumb then post entry 2 is used instead. I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Does the post thumbnail appear if the post has an image attached?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?..

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>

          <div class="post-thumb">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="post-entry-1">
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          </div>

        <? } else { ?>

          <div class="post-entry-2">
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          </div>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <p class="no-data">
        <?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found.' ); ?>
    </p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ah thank you Rarst that's basically what i'm doing but when, I view it in a browser. The posts seem to go out side of the wrapper, for some reason?

Comment: Is your resulting markup correct? [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) is staple tool to deal with that if you need one. If markup is fine then it is probably CSS issue, again Firebug rocks for that as well.

Comment: Sorry Rarst how do you mean markup? Do you mean is everthing where it should etc, in correct divs and so on?

Comment: Yes. Is resulting HTML output what you want it to be? Then wrong looks is issue with presentation (CSS) and not markup (HTML).

Comment: I think it seems to be the markup but i'm not sure, i'll see if I can get a presentation on the internet.

Comment: That markup is perfectly fine. You may have markup outside of this example on your page that is invalid, such as an unclosed `<div>` tag, but the problem isn't the markup here.

Comment: Ah ok lol I have chaecked countless times, so i'll check again. I have got an example up - http://hbk.weburton.co.uk/

Comment: I have a warning on there which I didn't get when viewing the layout using localhost

Comment: I have managed to add all the loop i've coded and am having problems with so hopefully it's easier to understand :)

Comment: Don't call `query_posts()` - you don't need it and doing it wrong anyway (no parameters). That's where warning comes from. Second your conditional containers drive me crazy. You clearly have amount of opening/closing `div` going wrong somewhere. Also `<? } else { ?>` should be `<?php } else { ?>`

Comment: Ah thank you so much Rarst so I should completely delete the query_post then? Sorry for the hassle, I am still a learner obviously. Everyone has been such a big help! I'll try what you said and see what the results are.

Comment: Yes, you only need to call `query_post()` to modify Loop, otherwise it works behind the scenes. It's hard to debug with lots of stuff going on. Just start with core code and add stuff like meta later, when important things work properly.

Answer (score 2):

One problem you may be having is that you have included an extra `</div>`

```
<!--Begin Post Entry-->
<div class="post-entry-2">
//your code
</div>
<!--End Post Entry-->

</div><!--End Post-->

</div><!--this appears to be extra-->
```

Try fixing that and see what happens.  Your loop seems to be fine, just that posts are being displayed outside of your wrapper.

The error you are receiving is pointing to the fact that you haven't supplied any arguments to `query_posts`.  Why are you using query_posts if you aren't supplying any arguments.  This function is only used when you intend to modify the default WP query.

Comment: Thank you so very much kevtrout, you have saved my day :) it's ok now. I just tried on localhost and it's all ok, thank you for your help it was greatly appreciated it really was.

Comment: Glad your problem has been solved.